# Error when casting pyarrow table to custom schema

Tags: casting, pyarrow

I am trying to write a dataframe to pyrarrow table and then casting this pyarrow table to a custom schema. I can read the dataframe to pyarrow table but when I cast it to custom schema I run into an error.
Some context: `filesCsv` is a list of csv filenames(with absolute path)

```
new_schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('termination_date',pa.timestamp("us")),
    pa.field('Employee_ID',pa.string()),
    pa.field('Full_Legal_Name', pa.string()),
    pa.field('First_Name', pa.string()),
    pa.field('Middle_Name', pa.string()),
    pa.field('Last_Name', pa.string()), 
    pa.field('businessTitle', pa.string()),
    pa.field('primaryWorkEmail', pa.string()),
    pa.field('Supervisory_Organization', pa.string()),
    pa.field('Primary_Work_Mobile_Phone', pa.string()),
    pa.field('Cost_Center', pa.string()),
    pa.field('date_extracted', pa.timestamp("us"))]
    )
timestmp='00:00:00'

for file in filesCsv:
    filenamep=file.split('_')  ## to reformat the date and remove timestamp from file.This 
     date will help in hive partitioning of dataset
    filenamep.pop(-1)
    hiveDate=filenamep[-1]
    ##print(hiveDate)
    hiveDate=hiveDate[:4]+'-'+hiveDate[4:6]+'-'+hiveDate[6:]+ ' '+timestmp ###creates a dates sting as "YYYY-MM-DD"
    ##print(hiveDate)
    hiveDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(hiveDate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ###'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    ##print(type(hiveDate))
    df_csv=pd.read_csv(file)
    ##print(type(df_csv))
    ##print(type(df_csv))
    date_extracted=pd.Series(hiveDate)  ### dtype='datetime64[ns]' pd.Series takes list as an argument. We will use pd.Series as the length of the list is less than columns in the dataframe
    ##print(date_extracted)
    ##print(type(date_extracted))
    df_csv.loc[:,'date_extracted']=pd.Series(date_extracted) 
    df_csv['date_extracted'].ffill(inplace=True)
    df_csv.columns
    print(df_csv.dtypes) ## list columns and data types
    ## print(type(df_csv))
    pq_tbl2=pa.Table.from_pandas(df_csv)
    pq_tbl2.schema
    pq_tbl2=pq_tbl2.cast(target_schema=new_schema)
    ##pq_file_name=''.join(filenamep)+'.parquet'
    ##print(pq_file_name)
    ##pq.write_table(pq_tbl2,pq_file_name, use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True)
```

I am getting this strange error. I have tried casting from the parquet file read into pyarrow table and see no error. I want to directly do this step from CSV file to dataframe to pyarrow table

ValueError: Target schema's field names are not matching the table's field names: ['401 : invalid username or password', 'date_extracted'], ['termination_date', 'Employee_ID', 'Full_Legal_Name', 'First_Name', 'Middle_Name', 'Last_Name', 'businessTitle', 'primaryWorkEmail', 'Supervisory_Organization', 'Primary_Work_Mobile_Phone', 'Cost_Center', 'date_extracted']

Comment: What do you mean by "casting from parquet file read into pyarrow table" vs "directly do this step from csv file to dataframe to pyarrow table"? Having sample code for each scenario would help.

Comment: My first approach was to simply write a csv file to parquet file without any schema changes. Then I read this parquet file into a pyarrow table and did the casting. That works.

Comment: This is a more information around the error.
pyarrow.Table
401 : invalid username or password: null
date_extracted: string
----
401 : invalid username or password: [1 nulls]
date_extracted: [["2021-06-07 00:00:00"]]